# PXE or other : deploy images on single board computers (SBC)

Tags: linux, networking, deployment, boot, pxe-boot

We have a few SBCs of various modeles (but a lot of freescale). When received, these SBCs are bare (no BIOS/U-boot). We generate linux embedded images with Yocto (using U-boot as bootloader), and we deploy it manually on SD cards.  This works well for now, when we are in test phase and don't have a lot of cards. But later, it'll be definitly to slow.

We have a central server for the network of the SBCs. Currently, this is a simple DHCP server, affecting IP address depending on the MAC address of the SBCs. We'd like to make it a PXE server. But as the memories of the SBCs are totally empty (no bootloader) when received, it seems that we have to manually flash them to put U-boot, and then configure it to boot using PXE. Our problem is the same than at the beginning.

Ideally, we'd like to plug the SBCs, and then control the deployment from the server, using a tool like Fog or DRBL/Clonezilla. Is there a way to do so easily, without flashing the SBCs one by one to install U-boot ?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your SBCs;

i.e. you could boot your SBC to a preloaded image located i.e. on a USB pendrive starting a PXE session that will install the desired image on the resident flash.

But probably if I were you I'd try a Jtag based approach (if your SBC has a Jtag connector); That's what embedded professionals do.

Comment: JTAG seems to be a little complicated, especially for us who aren't electronicans at all.
The boot on USB key could be nive, but without bootloader preinstalled, it will be difficult.

Comment: Some SBC include minimally the ability to boot from USB when present (code included in the mask). If not  your safest bid is Jtag; and it is not a complicated option. It is the industry standard.